# What's the difference between "verständlicherweise" & "selbstverständlich"?

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

I have recently came across the word "*verständlicherweise*", like in the following sentences:

> - Die Freude über das Wiedersehen war verständlicherweise groß.
> - Die Diagnose hat sein Leben verständlicherweise zutiefst erschüttert.
> - Jeder mit kleinen Kindern bevorzugt verständlicherweise eine Teilzeitarbeit.

I am aware of the different meanings & usages of "*selbstverständlich*", so my question is: wouldn't "*selbstverständlich*" convey the same meaning in those examples?

Comment: I'm not sure this couldn't be answered with a dictionary. Per Wiktionary, "*verständlicherweise*" = "understandably", "*selbstverständlich*" = "naturally".

Comment: @RDBury "selbstverständlich" means naturally, obviously, certainly etc, and all of these sounded acceptable (to me) in the examples I listed. I couldn't find a sentence where "verständlicherweise" can't be replaced with "selbstverständlich".

Comment: The meanings are similar, but I don't see why the different English translations wouldn't explain the difference. "You are, understandably, afraid of tigers." is different than "You are, naturally, afraid of tigers." I'm not a native speaker so there may be some subtlety in the meaning that I'm not aware of, but the dictionary definitions are different. Is there something about them you still don't understand? If so. you should include that in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Verständlicherweise* (as does the English translation *understandably*) means, that you can agree after having thought about it or having taken the viewpoint.

*Selbstverständlich* (*obviously* being a close counterpart) means, that no effort is required after being given the facts.

In your first example *selbstverständlich* would be too strong in my opinion: We all know people, where an encounter provides limited joy. Likewise in the second example: Quite a few diagnoses can be somewhat ugly without being shocking. Even in the third example the gain of time has to be set in relation to the decrease in salary; so consideration **is** required.

Summarized: in all cases *verständlicherweise* seems the better choice (in absence of further details).